# Error while opening a url with Chrome :selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win_20.0.1133.0\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Chrome browser : 15.0.874.5
Chrome driver : chromedriver_win_20.0.1133.0
browser opens up with an blank page and following error is thrown

```
[0704/103822:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(129)] pipe error: 109
[0704/103822:ERROR:automation_proxy.cc(367)] Channel error in AutomationProxy.
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(298): error: Value of: browser.get() Actual: false`enter code here` Expected: true
```

how can we avoid this issue ?

Comment: Chrome browser : 15.0.874.5
Chrome driver : chromedriver_win_20.0.1133.0 

browser opens up with an blank page and following error is thrown

[0704/103822:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(129)] pipe error: 109
[0704/103822:ERROR:automation_proxy.cc(367)] Channel error in AutomationProxy.
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(298): error: Value of: browser.get()
  Actual: false`enter code here`
Expected: true

Comment: how can we avoid this issue ?

Comment: When using `driver.get(" ");` be sure to include the `http://` or else the URL will not be valid.

From your example, `driver.get("http://www.google.com");` would be required.

Comment: I would suggest you keep your Chrome browser & ChromeDriver versions as near as possible. (I.e Chrome 20 with ChromeDriver v20, instead of Chrome v15 with ChromeDriver v20)